# Functional inheritance js without prototype (return overload methods)

Tags: javascript

Just started learning this topic. Issue I dont understand how it works. There're no errors neigher expected result. In the example I short code to 1 alert, but it doesn't work

```
function App(){
   function render(){}
   this.run = function() {
       render();
   }
}

function MainWindow(){
   App.call(this);
   function render(){
       renderFirstController();
       renderSecondController();
       renderThirdController();
   }
   this.render = render;
}

function FirstController(){
   MainWindow.call(this);
   function render(){
       console.log("Good");
       // renderFirtsBlock();
       // renderSecondBlock();
       // renderThirdBlock();
   }
   this.renderFirstController = render;
}

function ready(){
   let app = new App();
   app.run();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Maybe I dont understand JS OOP, but I expect App.render as not empty function but assigned 3 x 3 = 9 inner functions. Also someone advanced to create new objects. But I dont know where to create. This is example of 1x3x3 tree, but it could expand to 1xnxn; Also I should be able to catch "maximum call stack size exceeded". So there's the problem

Comment: I have edited your code into an executable sample, which does *not* exhibit the behaviour you describe…

Comment: `this.render = render();`  Doesn't really make much sense, you will be assigning `undefined ` to `this.render`

Comment: maybe I write incorrect description. This was a shortcut of my project. I try to make MVC, so there should be several controllers and MainWindow. I wanted render function in one MainWindow which overloaded by other controllers. As I understand interpreter (browser) should go deep to children, get this function and return to parent. Seems like tree. I mean: render(empty) => render(1, 2, 3) => render(1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, .... , 3-3) in MainWindow

Comment: Your code is neither attempting to do that, nor does it show the error you encounter. You'll have to rephrase your question to something answerable…

Comment: okey, I rewrite my question, I'll be glad you look at it.

Comment: Your `MainWindow` constructor creates a `render` property on the instance, but the `run` method defined in the `App` does only call the (empty) `render` function *from its local scope*, not the `this.render` method.

Comment: Also, your `ready` function creates an `App` instance not a `FirstController` instance, so the `app` doesn't know anything about the rest of your code.